# Does each computer/smart phone use electromagnetic wave with different frequency to communicate when they're connected to a WLAN?

Tags: router, wireless, ieee-802.11, cisco-wireless

I read some papers about WLAN and Wi-Fi. They say that modern WLAN/Wi-Fi uses a kind of technology called "OFDM(Orthogonal Frequency Division Multiplexing)".

My understanding is: ODFM means that each host(PC, laptop, smart phone, etc.) uses electromagnetic wave with different frequency to communicate with the wireless router(or hotspot)?

Comment: Removed the off-topic host question.

Comment: I think you may be referring to OFDMA, which was introduced with 802.11ax. OFDM stations will use the entire channel, and OFDMA may subdivide the channel to allow multiple access concurrently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My understanding is: ODFM means that each host(PC, laptop, smart
> phone, etc.) uses electromagnetic wave with different frequency to
> communicate with the wireless router(or hotspot)?

What OFDM does is split a single data stream to multiple frequencies. A host will use a range of frequencies to communicate to the WAP. Multiple hosts must share the frequency range, and only one host at a time uses that frequency range. Wi-Fi forces the hosts to take turns to share the frequency range.